# Contrapostive proof for "If $a$ and $b$ are elements of group $G$ such that $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$, then $G$ is abelian".

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I am aware that you can do this proof directly. Essentially by expanding the terms and using the cancellation property along with inverses. However, I wanted to know if it were possible to prove this statement by making use of the contrapositive.

The proof being...

Assume $G$ is not abelian,
then $(ab)^2 = abab$ which is not equivalent to $aabb = a^2b^2$.

This feels weaker than the original way that I proved it. But, I wanted to ask you all!

Comment: You have to be rigorous about the statement, in order to produce the correct negation...

Comment: If the statement "If a and b are elements of group G such that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$, then G is abelian" reads: if (for every a,b of G, $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$), then G is abelian" we have that the contrapositive will be: "if G is **not** abelian, then there are a,b in G, such that $(ab)^2 \ne a^2b^2$".

Comment: Your proof is not rigorous enough. To begin with, what are $a,b$? Are these any new two elements? Even if the group is not abelian, some elements always commute. So you need to say that if $G$ is not abelian then there are some $a,b\in G$ such that $ab\ne ba$. And then explain why in this case $abab$ is indeed not equal to $a^2b^2$. (it is correct, but you didn't explain why)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: @Mark Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: The claim in the title is, in my opinion, false. It would be correct if it said *If for all elements $a,b\in G$ we have $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$, then $G$ is abelian.* The way it is currently phrased seems to suggest (to me at least) that it suffices that the identity holds for *some* $a$ and $b$. This obviously won't allow us to conclude that $G$ would be abelian.

Comment: Or, in other words, in the present phrasing *such that* narrows down the scope of the main statement. It would still be correct to claim that *For all elements $a,b$ such that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2$ the subgroup $\langle a,b\rangle\le G$ is abelian.* When *such that* is used like this, the claim should somehow depend on the choice of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: As stated in the title the claim is false. Take $a$ and/or $b$ in $Z(G)$, whatever the (non centerless) group $G$ is. Quantifiers are not details.

Comment: I think you have difficulties writing this in unambiguous English.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Have you got an idea of the native language of the asker? The (verbatim copied) statement in your second comment is non-sensical. The if-part absolutely needs a quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use the fact that in a group, if $g \neq g'$, then $gh \neq g'h$ and $hg \neq hg'$ (this is easy to show).

Suppose that $G$ is not abelian. Then there exist $a,b \in G$ such that $ab \neq ba$.

Then, $eabe \neq ebae \implies a^{-1}aabbb^{-1} \neq a^{-1}ababb^{-1} \implies aabb \neq abab$ using the property above.

Hence, there are $a,b \in G$ such that $(ab)^2 \neq a^2b^2$.

Comment: Thank you! I have been challenging myself to prove these statements differently than I did during my undergrad. So, this has been incredibly helpful and insightful. Thank you so much for your guidance!